# Normalization and Boundary conditions of Scattering states when computing phase shifts

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

When reading about scattering theory I came across the following equation which gives the exact formula for computing phase shifts.

\begin{equation}i^l(2l+1)e^{i\delta_l}\sin{\delta_l}=-\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}\int_0^\infty V(r)[krj_l(kr)]u_l(r)dr\end{equation}

Where $j_l$ are the spherical Bessel functions and $u_l$ is the solution of the Schroedinger equation. I tried to calculate the phase shifts for the following potential:
\begin{equation}
V(r)=\frac{10^{-4}\hbar^2}{2mr^2} 
\end{equation}

I'm aware that you can compute the phase shifts for this potential without making any approximations but I still wanted to try and compute them another way so I solved the Schroedinger equation numerically using [Numerov's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerov%27s_method). Using this method the first boundary condition has to be that $u_{l}(0)=0$, but the second boundary is completely arbitrary since scattering states are not normalizable anyway. Depending on the second boundary condition we can get many solutions of the type:

\begin{equation}
\bar{u_l}(r)=Nu_l(r)
\end{equation}

The phase shifts can't possibly depend on the constant $N$, but from the first equation, we can see that for different values of $N$ the phase shifts are different. So my questions are, what are the correct boundary conditions to use when trying to solve the Schroedinger equation for scattering states and how does the first equation give us a correct result if we can alter the Normalization of our wave function however we wish?